# Lightning button Variant - To appear blue/white and appear center aligned

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system, slds, lightning-button

Trying to build a form and I put 2 buttons in the form. Want 1 of the button as to appear blue and other to appear white.  I created below component:

Searchform.cmp

```
<aura:component >   
<!-- FORM -->
    <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center">
        <lightning:layoutItem>
        <form class="slds-form--stacked">  
        <lightning:button label="Search" 
                          variant="brand"
                          class="slds-button"
                          onclick="{!c.clickSearch}"/>
         <lightning:button label="New" 
                          variant="white"
                          onclick="{!c.clickNew}"/>                  
        </form>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout> 
</aura:component>
```

I use an app component to see the result. I added the component in an application component like this:

```
<aura:application>
<c:Searchform/> 
</aura:application>
```

But I do not see any styles applied to the `button` and it does not appear in the `center` when I use `horizontalAlign="center"`. What I might be missing here? I would like the styles to be applied and button to appear in the center of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application needs to use [SLDS](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_slds.htm):

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
  <c:Searchform />
</aura:application>
```

Comment: Cool! That make sense. I completely missed that piece.

Comment: I have a lightning input field in the form. I want the input field and two buttons to appear in the same level(along side) instead of one after the other vertically. I tried `<form class="slds-form slds-form_horizontal">` but no difference. Sorry if I am not supposed to ask this as part of this question/comment.

Comment: @SfdcBat You're not supposed to, but I generally don't mind. Anyways, If you want to line them up correctly, use `slds-grid` and slds-size elements; I think you want to use `slds-size_1-of-2` and `slds-size_1-of-4`.

Comment: Apologies for that. I did ask another question about this. I will try out slds grid to align. If you prefer you can answer my latest question meanwhile I try this.